# How to test the low power condition on Android

Tags: android

I wondered if anyone had any ideas about how to simulate low power conditions on Android (ie the pop-up notification that occurs) on the G1, say.

The adb am command lets you broadcast intents but, I think, maybe not system ones. Anyway,

$ am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW }

doesn't help.

Any ideas? Do the performance test cases help?

Thanks in advance....
Ewan

Comment: Actually your command works. Tested on a non-rooted Gingerbread Nexus S. Thanks! I was looking for a way to test low battery with a Bluetooth app (can't do it on the emulator)..

Answer (score 3):

[Device Power](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#power) in the Android Emulator lets you set the remaining charge.

Comment: Thanks, thought of that after posting - too long on actual devices.... Unfortunately the emulator doesn't have the low power dialog that pops up on a g1 that is T-Mobile/Google specific I guess.